# Execution failed for task ':amplifyPush'

Tags: android, aws-amplify

Error while running amplifyPush task:

```
Task :amplifyPush
Note: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory

For more information on AWS Profiles, see:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

init failed
Error: Profile configuration is missing for: default
at Object.getProfiledAwsConfig (C:\Users\phili\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-provider-awscloudformation\src\system-config-manager.js:90:17)
at Object.getAwsConfig (C:\Users\phili\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-provider-awscloudformation\src\configuration-manager.ts:727:45)
at Object.run (C:\Users\phili\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-provider-awscloudformation\src\initializer.js:27:50)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)

Task :amplifyPush FAILED

Execution failed for task ':amplifyPush'.

Process 'command 'amplify.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

Open config and credential files under folder:

~/.aws/credentials (Linux & Mac) or %USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials (Windows)

Add the [default] section in config file.

Make sure the [default] section in credentials file is there and has correct access key and password.